# Algebraic number, Minimal polynomial and basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can someone help me with these question?

a) Prove that  $a = \sqrt{11} - \sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic
 number, by finding a polynomial with integer coefficients that has $a$ as a root.

b) Find the minimal polynomial of the number $a$ from (a) above.  Prove that it is the minimal polynomial by proving that it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$.

c) Give a basis for the vector space $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: At the end of the first line was it supposed to be "...is an algebraic number..." , or what?

Comment: And what have you tried, what are your insights, thoughts, **efforts** ...?

Comment: In fact I am confused and I don't know if what I have is correct or not

Comment: The second part of the question confuses me of the whole thing. Anyway, thank you for alerting me on the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**  The questions were originally stated about the number $a = \sqrt{11} + \sqrt{2}$, so the answer concerns that value of $a$.

---

Notice that
$$
a^2 = \left( \sqrt{11} + \sqrt{2} \right)^2 = 13 + 2 \sqrt{22}.$$
Hence,
$$
a^2 - 13 = 2\sqrt{22},
$$
and
$$
\left( a^2 - 13 \right)^2 = 88.
$$
Therefore,
$$
a^4 - 26a^2 + 81 = 0.
$$

You can check that the four roots of $p(x) = x^4 - 26x^2 + 81$ are
$$
\pm \sqrt{11} \pm \sqrt{2}.
$$
(These are called *conjugates* of $a$.)  Why is $p(x)$ irreducible?

If $p$ were reducible, then it would factor as $p(x) = s(x) t(x)$, where $\deg s + \deg t = 4$.  Certainly, neither factor can be linear because it would be of the form $x - r$, where $r$ is one of the roots, but these are not integers.  The remaining possibility is that $s$ and $t$ are quadratic, but you can check that $s(x) = (x - r_1)(x - r_2)$ does not have integer coefficients for any roots $r_1, r_2 \in \left\{ \pm \sqrt{11} \pm \sqrt{2} \right\}$.  Therefore, $p$ is the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

To find a basis for $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, note that
$$
\Bbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{11} + \sqrt{2} \right) = \Bbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{11}, \sqrt{2} \right).
$$
(Can you find the explicit polynomial that expresses $\sqrt{11}$ in terms of $a$?  How about $\sqrt{2}$?  How about $\sqrt{22}$?)

Since every element of $\Bbb{Q}(a)$ is of the form
$$
c_0 + c_1 \sqrt{11} + c_2 \sqrt{2} + c_3 \sqrt{22},
$$
the basis is
$$
\left\{ 1, \sqrt{11}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{22} \right\}.
$$

Comment: I think you are right. I only got the first question right but I did not know how to go about the rest. Thank you.

Comment: I just realized the operation sign is minus instead of plus so I have changed it. I Hope it won't affect the answer so much.

Comment: I am going to leave the answer *as is,* especially since $\sqrt{11} - \sqrt{2}$ is a conjugate (has the same minimal polynomial).

Comment: OK.thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The thing a field has different from an ordinary vector space is that you can multiply two elements. (and you can divide by a nonzero element)

$1$ is an element of $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$. Also,the set $\{ 1 \}$ is linearly dependent.

Is $\alpha$ linearly dependent on $1$? If so, then $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbf{Q}$ and we've found a basis.

Otherwise, $\{ 1, \alpha \}$ is a linearly independent set. Is $\alpha^2$ linearly dependent on $\{ 1, \alpha \}$? If so, then we've found a basis for the ring $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha]$ (and this ring turns out to be the same as the field $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$, since it's finite dimensional).

Otherwise, $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2 \}$ is a linearly independent set. And so forth. If you have some other way to write these elements -- e.g. you can write everything as a linear combination of $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11}, \sqrt{22}$ -- then it may help to do 'row reduction' to simplify the basis before you continue along.

If you don't, however, but you now determine $\alpha^3$ is linearly dependent on $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2 \}$... well, that linear dependence can be seen to give the minimal polynomial, if you write it out!